# Prevent clr compiler from converting a method into c#

Tags: c++, clr

I want to make this method remain in native because on compiling the `__fastcall` is being converted into `__stdcall` How do I make sure that the clr compiler remains this method native?

```
static void* __fastcall FindCallOffset(VMTBasePointer* _this, unsigned char* addr);
```

Comment: It is crucial to compile this function without /clr in effect so the compiler will emit native code instead of IL.  It is a per-file setting, a static library project helps a lot.  Good odds that you'll need #pragma managed(push, off) and #pragma managed(pop) around the #include for the .h file in your C++/CLI source file.  Do improve the question if this does not help, it is far too brief to tell what went wrong.

Comment: The __fastcall was converted to __stdcall then to IL which caused the code to break.